# php generate a select box having dropdown years of -5 years and +5 years

Tags: php

I want to generate a select box drop down list having date ranges of -3 years and +5 years dynamically using PHP.

For example:

```
<select name="years">
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option> // Current Year
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
    <option value="2022">2022</option>
    <option value="2023">2023</option>
    <option value="2024">2024</option>
</select>
```

Something like this. And each year the list will automatically get updated like in 2020 the min range will become 2017 and max range will become 2025. How to do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use date() to get the year and for loop to get the desired result.

```
echo '<select name="years">' . PHP_EOL;
for($i = date("Y")-3; $i <=date("Y")+5; $i++){
    echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</select>';
```

Output:

```
<select name="years">
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
<option value="2021">2021</option>
<option value="2022">2022</option>
<option value="2023">2023</option>
<option value="2024">2024</option>
</select>
```

https://3v4l.org/jIPKl

Comment: It creates a new line in the HTML output making the code easier to debug/read if you view source

Comment: okay.. so it works without PHP_EOL too.. just using for debugging purposes. Fine.. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes mostly for debugging and for those with degrees or OCD :-) Here you can see the difference in output https://3v4l.org/ZRdLl that is what it will look like if you or someone else looks at the source of the webpage.

Answer (score 3):

```
// get current year
$curYear = date('Y');

// create range of required years and iterate over them
foreach(range($curYear - 3, $curYear + 5) as $year) {
    echo "<option value='$year'>$year</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is from scratch, you can use this:

```
echo "<select name='years'>";
   for($i=-5; $i <= 5; $i++){
        $test = date('Y', strtotime($i.'year'));
        echo '<option value='.$test.'>'.$test.'</option>';
   }
echo "</select>";
```

This will output what you are looking for. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$current_year =  date("Y");

?>

<select>
    <?php
       for ($i=-3; $i <6 ; $i++) {
    ?>
   <option value=" <?php echo($current_year + $i);  ?>"> <?php echo($current_year + $i);  ?>
   </option>
   <?php
      }
    ?>
</select>
```